# Best way to wait a method that get data asynchronously from database to populate a listview

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, asynchronous, retrofit

I want to populate a listView with data retrieved from DB asynchronously, 
the problem Is that if I set the adapter, it throws null pointer because the data not arrieved yet, when I recieve data one method is executed, so what I can call in this method to populate my listview? I tried passing the layout to this class to populate directly the listview when the data is recieved but don't worked (nothing happened)

I thought using AsyncTask was a good idea adding wait() and when this "retriever data method" is triggered  call notify() but I don't know how to call notify() from an asynctask from another class...

I'm also not sure if asynktask is the best way of doing this, any ideas?
I'm using retrofit2 if it helps

Code of listview create/populate

```
private List<TmOfsDTO> prepareList() {
    List<TmOfsDTO> list;
    try {
        // Create list of items
        ListObtainer listObtainer = new ListObtainer(this);
        list = listObtainer.getTmOfsDTOList(user); // this method returns list of objects from DB
    } catch (Exception e) {
        list = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}

private void populateListView(List<TmOfsDTO> lista) {

    // Build Adapter
    OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this, 0, lista);
    // orderAdapter.getView()

    Log.d("LSO", ".....");
    // Configure listview
    //View rootView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_ordenes, null);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOrdenes);
    listView.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
    //listView.invalidateViews();
    //listView.refreshDrawableState();
    Log.d("LSO", ".......");
```

**Last update:**
**
I was doing right the notify when I was recieving data, passing the adapter to the class and calling:
    orderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

but the problem is I was missing to add each item with:
    orderAdapter.add(orden);

before notify, now seem to work good**

Comment: loaders, read about loaders framework

Comment: " the problem Is that if I set the adapter, it throws null pointer because the data not arrieved yet" - this part sounds suspect. If you have a valid adapter it shouldn't matter if the data has arrived yet or not (it should just show nothing in the list until data is added to the adapter)

Comment: Could you please pass the relevant logcat part? And the matching piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you logcat show above the `lista` is null. You are passing this list to the adapter. But if you have not initialized the variable `lista` it will throw a null pointer exception.

Suggest to initialize the List you passing to the adapter. Then when the data comes in you add the data `lista` and call the method `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Following seems to cause the null pointer exception

```
} catch (Exception e) {
        list = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So beside initializing you should also not assign null.

Comment: handling bad code design in catch is not a solid solution.

Comment: how I can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() when I recieve data if  The adapter is created after calling the getListFromDB method?

Comment: Make  OrderAdapter orderAdapter a class variable and then when you receive the data you set  orderAdapter.setDayaSetChanged()

Comment: And indeed the try and catch is definitely a good solution. But that was just to point out the current fail point. The code should be improved indeed. But one step at the time. Fail, fix, improve

Comment: thanks buddy I solved it passing the adapter to the inner class that recieve data and adding the items to it and then calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best using a RecyclerView, anyway. This is part of the new support libraries and is way more efficient than the older ListView.

Some key questions here are whether or not the database is local. If your have an sqlite3 database on the phone that you're loading from then you should have written some classes that load the database information into objects that you can store into an array and pass into the RecyclerView.Adapter very easily.

If you are loading this remotely, then you would be 100% better off syncing the data onto your phone using an AsyncTask before trying to load the RecyclerView, otherwise you'll get those errors.

You could load ONE item into an ArrayList from a remote database, pass that to the RecyclerView, and then carry on loading from the remote database and notifying the RecyclerView of a change upon each item being added to the list.

Comment: adding sqlite and sync it with remote db sounds good... but needs too much time to implement now, I need an easier solution because I need listview working for today

Answer (score 0):

Create a different constructor for your adapter, one that does not receive data to display in it. When you have that, it will not crash.

To get your data inside, create a local `List` of your items and populate it with something like:

```
public void setData(List<MyObject> data){
this.mData = data;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also, don't forget to handle possible null pointer errors in methods such as getItem.

Answer (score 0):

lets say we are in viewDidLoad method. I'd suggest you to do the following:

- in your adapter class create public method: setData, which calls adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
- send request to backend by passing callback function
- display loading/progress dialog
- initialize adapter by passing empty array(not null)
- when callback is fired and you get the list call adapter's setData and hide the progress dialog.

Comment: "send request to backend by passing callback function" How I can do this

Comment: by using delegates or other callback mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fragments just call `setAdapter()` another time after data extraction